# If the sum of two conditional probabilities on a probability space is greater than one does that violate the space's properties?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $A, B, C$ are pairwise disjoint events on a probability space. If $P(A|B) = 0.6$ and $P(B|C) = 0.6$, does that violate the property of a probability space that $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) \le 1$?

Comment: If they are pairwise disjoint then $P(A\mid B)=0$ assuming $P(B) >0$, and so on.  If they have zero probability then the sum of the probabilities will not exceed one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint (that is, they cannot occur together) then we will have that $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)\le 1$$

However, note that if they are pairwise disjoint $P(A\wedge B)=P(B\wedge C)=0$. Thus, the values for the conditional probabilities you provide do not hold: they are either 0 or undefined.

Note that the only atomic events that can have non-null probability, given that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint, are
$$A\wedge\neg B\wedge\neg C$$
$$\neg A\wedge B\wedge\neg C$$
$$\neg A\wedge\neg B\wedge C$$
$$\neg A\wedge\neg B\wedge \neg C$$

Note that the inequality (not necessarily equality) holds because the event $\neg A\wedge\neg B\wedge \neg C$ can have non-null probability.

Answer (score 0):

no it doesn't. The trivial example is for any event A, P(A | A) is always 1.

Comment: So I guess just the sum of probabilities of each single event in a space must amount to 1?